# How does dereference work C++

Tags: operator-keyword

I have trouble understanding what happens when calling &*pointer

```
int j=8;
int* p = &j;
```

When I print in my compiler I get the following

```
j = 8 , &j =  00EBFEAC  p = 00EBFEAC , *p = 8 , &p =  00EBFEA0 
&*p= 00EBFEAC

cout << &*p gives  &*p = 00EBFEAC which is p itself
```

& and * have same operator precedence.I thought &*p would translate to `&(*p)--> &(8)` and expected compiler error.

How does compiler deduce this result?

Answer (score 4):

You are stumbling over something interesting: Variables, strictly spoken, *are not values*, but *refer to* values. `8` *is an* integer value. After `int i=8`, `i` *refers to* an integer value. The difference is that it could refer to a different value.

In order to obtain the value, `i`  must be dereferenced, i.e. the value stored in the memory location which `i` stands for must be obtained.  This dereferencing is performed implicitly in C whenever a value of the type which the variable references is requested: `i=8; printf("%d", i)` results in the same output as `printf("%d", 8)`. That is funny because variables are essentially aliases for addresses, while numeric literals are aliases for immediate values. In C these very different things are syntactically treated identically. A variable can stand in for a literal in an expression and will be automatically dereferenced. The resulting machine code makes that very clear. Consider the two functions below. Both have the same return type, int. But `f` has a variable in the return statement which must be dereferenced so that its value can be returned (in this case, it is returned in a register):

```
int i = 1;
int g(){ return 1; }  // literal
int f(){ return i; }  // variable
```

If we ignore the housekeeping code, the functions each translate into a sigle machine instruction. The corresponding assembler (from icc) is for `g`:

```
    movl      $1, %eax                                      #5.17
```

That's pretty starightforward: Put 1 in the register eax.

By contrast, `f` translates to

```
    movl      i(%rip), %eax                                 #4.17
```

This puts the value at the address in register rip plus offset i in the register eax. It's refreshing to see how a variable name is just an address (offset) alias to the compiler.

The necessary dereferencing should now be obvious. It would be more logical to write `return *i` in order to return 1, and write `return i` only for functions which return references — or pointers.

In your example it is indeed illogical to a degree that

```
int j=8;
int* p = &j;
printf("%d\n", *p);
```

prints 8 (i.e, p is actually dereferenced twice); but that `&(*p)` yields the address of the object pointed to by p (which is the address value stored in p), and is not interpreted as `&(8)`. The reason is that in the context of the address operator a variable (or, in this case, the L-value obtained by dereferencing p) is *not*  implicitly dereferenced the way it is in other contexts.

When the attempt was made to create a logical, orthogonal language — Algol68 —, `int i=8` indeed declared an alias for 8. In order to declare a variable the long form would have been **`ref`**`int m = loc int := 3`. Consequently what we call a pointer or reference would have had the type `ref ref int` because actually two dereferences are needed to obtain an integer value.

Comment: Thank you pointing out using assembler code. It make it more clear to me

Answer (score 2):

j is an int with value 8 and is stored in memory at address 00EBFEAC.

&j gives the memory address of variable j (00EBFEAC).

int* p = &j Here you define a variable p which you define being of type int *, namely a value of an address in memory where it can find an int. You assign it &j, namely an address of an int -> which makes sense.

*p gives you the value associated with the address stored in p.
The address stored in p points to an int, so *p gives you the value of that int, namely 8.

& p is the address of where the variable p itself is stored

&*p gives you the address of the value the memory address stored in p points to, which is indeed p again. &(*p) -> &(j) -> 00EBFEAC

Answer (score 1):

Think about `&j` itself (or even `&(j)`). According to your logic, shouldn't `j` evaluate to 8 and result in `&8`, as well? Dereferencing a pointer or evaluating a variable results in an *lvalue*, which is a value that you can assign to or take the address of.

The **L** in "lvalue" refers to the **left** in "left hand side of the assignment", such as `j = 10` or `*p = 12`. There are also rvalues, such as `j + 10`, or `8`, which obviously cannot be assigned to.

That's just a basic explanation. [In C++ there's a lot more to it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3601602/what-are-rvalues-lvalues-xvalues-glvalues-and-prvalues), with various classes of values (but that thread might be too advanced for your current needs).

Comment: Dereference a pointer--> you get lvalue on which you can take address of operator. I agree. What would be the intermediate lvalue of *p in the complex step of doing &*p  ?

Comment: What do you mean by "intermediate lvalue"? `*p` is an lvalue, and since p points to j, it's the same lvalue as `j`.

Comment: I got the answer thank you! I was under impression *p in (&*p) evaluates to &(8) , so was confused . Now I am clear that *p in &*p evaluates to &(*p)--> &(j) --> p

Comment: @Sree Great then you can accept the answer if it solved your problem :) And yes you can think of if that way conceptually, but really there's no such "rewriting" going on. `*p` on the left side really is equivalent to `j`.