# Scope resolution and the this operator

Tags: c++, c

In a (C++) class I took recently the teacher mentioned that using the `->` operator was a tiny bit slower than using dot notation and dereferencing your pointer manually (e.g. `(*ptr)`).

1. Is this true, and, if so, why?
2. Does this apply to C as well?

Comment: Since `a->b` is just syntactic sugar for `(*a).b`, I highly doubt that.

Comment: @unwind Well since you can overload `->` and `*`, you could in principle be mischievous and insert a `sleep(n)` into the `->` implementation. But yeah …

Comment: @unwind yeah, that's what I thought as well
@KonradRudolph `Some men just want to watch the world burn` :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `->` operator is neither slower or faster than `.` operator. The fact is that *dereferencing* something is slower than just access to a memory location, because there is one more indirection. And this is a fact of life, either in C and C++ and any other language.

In C++, you have also *references*, so you can dereference something using the `.` too! So the problem here is not *arrow-vs-dot*, the problem is if the compiler can go straight to a value or if it must search for its address before.

Comment: `you have also references` yeah, but he definitely meant dereferencing a *pointer*, not "dereference a reference" (or whatever it's called).

Comment: The OP (as I understood) was not talking about pointer vs. direct object access but different notations of accessing an object through a pointer, namely `p->member` vs. `(*p).member`, which are absolutely and categorically identical (in their default implementation). To Marcus: Get your money back.

Comment: `Get your money back` I'm Swede. University's free. But if I'd payed for it, I would definitely demand my money back.

Comment: @PeterSchneider Oh... I guess you're right! Well, then the answer would turn into a "**NO**" :)

Comment: That dereferencing something is slower " this is a fact of life, either in C and C++ and any other language." While that is correct, optimizing compilers -- most notably JIT compilers which have more information at hand -- can possibly optimize away the dereferencing if they can prove that the reference keeps pointing to the same object (which in C++ for example is always true for "references").

Comment: As an example, using a variable instead of a literal also involves an indirection, as I layed out elsewhere (cf. http://stackoverflow.com/a/32736116/3150802). When playing around with the code I saw that the compiler would translate `int i=11; int f(){ return i*i; }` into a simple "return 121" unless I excplicitly switched optimizing off. Comparable optimizations should happen with pointers.